How can I return a list of IP addresses that doesn't include any I've already used?
In Google Sheets, I track IP addresses that are assigned to devices.
For example,

in column B I have a list of devices;
in Column C I have the IP address that is assigned to the device
In Column F I list my valid IP addresses pool.

I also have a Conditional format rule that highlights in red any duplicated IP addresses in Column C:
=COUNTIF(C:C,C4)>1

I'm trying to figure out a way to add a list of "available" IP addresses that would represent valid IP addresses from the pool that have not already been assigned.
I'm not sure how to proceed.
Link to example spreadsheet
Sample Data




A
B
C
D
E
F




1








2

Equipment
IP Applied


Address Pool


3








4

DEVICE 1
192.168.254.2


192.168.254.1


5

DEVICE 2
192.168.254.3


192.168.254.2


6

DEVICE 3



192.168.254.3


7

DEVICE 4
192.168.254.7


192.168.254.4


8

DEVICE 5



192.168.254.5


9

DEVICE 6



192.168.254.6


10

DEVICE 7



192.168.254.7


11

DEVICE 8



192.168.254.8




You can use COUNTIF with FILTER to return your list without any IPs that have been used:
=FILTER(list, LEN(list), NOT(COUNTIF(used, list)))

# Using your sample data
=FILTER(F4:F, LEN(F4:F), NOT(COUNTIF(C4:C, F4:F)))

COUNTIF  FILTER  LEN  NOT

FILTER returns each value in list where the following conditions are both TRUE:

The LEN of the value is a non-zero number; i.e. not blank
COUNTIF returns zero/FALSE which is changed to not-zero/TRUE using NOT. i.e. returns TRUE if the value doesn't appear in the range used.



Ideally, you would place this formula somewhere out of the way and then point a data validation Dropdown (from a range) at the column where you place this formula and use that dropdown in your used column to select IP addresses as needed.
